# Why can't I add a DataTrigger to my control's Triggers collection?

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

Why cant I code like this

```
<Border Width="130" Height="70">
    <Border.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentStatus}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ListBoxItemBorder}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentStatus}" Value="200">
            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ListBoxItemBorderInactive}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Border.Triggers>
</Border>
```

I get this error

```
Failed object initialization (ISupportInitialize.EndInit). 
Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger.  
Error at object '4_T' in markup file
```

What am I doing wrong plz help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Abe is correct and explains the limitations well. One thing you might want to consider is:

Instead of having two border styles, and trying to pick between them based on a trigger...

Use a single style on your border, this style's setters represent your 'normal' look.
This style also contains your DataTrigger, and your DataTrigger has a collection of setters which essentially represents your second style (which have higher priority than the standard setters when this trigger evaluates to true!

Edit:

Something like this -

```
<Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="BorderStyle">
    <!-- These setters are the same as your normal style when none of your triggers are true -->
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentStatus}" Value="0">
            <!-- These setters are the same as your ListBoxItemBorder style -->
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentStatus}" Value="200">
            <!-- These setters are the same as your ListBoxItemBorderInactive style -->
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately, only `EventTriggers` can be applied directly to elements. If you want to use a `Trigger` or `DataTrigger`, they have to be in a `Style`, `ControlTemplate`, or `DataTemplate`.

From the resource names, it looks like this is a `Border` inside a `ListBoxItem` `ControlTemplate`.  You could easily move the triggers into the template's triggers collection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way for no limitations triggers.

Example:

```
 <Border Width="130" Height="100" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}">

        </ListBox>
        <tg:TriggerExtensions.Triggers>
            <tg:TriggerCollections>
                <tg:DataTriggerInfo Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus}" Value="0">
                    <tg:DataTriggerInfo.Setters>
                        <tg:SetterInfo ElementName="lstItems" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxRed}"/>
                    </tg:DataTriggerInfo.Setters>
                </tg:DataTriggerInfo>
                <tg:DataTriggerInfo Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus}" Value="0" IsInvert="True">
                    <tg:DataTriggerInfo.Setters>
                        <tg:SetterInfo ElementName="lstItems" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxBlue}"/>
                    </tg:DataTriggerInfo.Setters>
                </tg:DataTriggerInfo>
            </tg:TriggerCollections>
        </tg:TriggerExtensions.Triggers>
    </Border>
```

Link [Sample](https://github.com/Ali-YousefiTelori/ExampleOfMvvmGo)

Link Component [Github](https://github.com/Ali-YousefiTelori/MvvmGo)